# Scion Underworlds in Geist's Cosmology

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, scion, geist-the-sin-eaters

Does anyone have advice for combining the underworld rules from *Scion* and *Geist* without the mechanics bumping into each other? Like a botched exorcism opening to a gate to Scion's Mictlan, or a Geist of some sort emerging out of Helheim? (These are only examples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having played Scion, I can tell you this much: there is a LOT missing from the Scion books. This is mechanically a nightmare, however it's great if you want to develop a good story.

Having never actually played Geist, my recommendation is to develop your own rules, however here's what I can tell you from Scion:

- Death is not permanent in Scion
- Scion World characters can restore the dead to life through underworld quests (I think there are god level charms that reverse death completely)
- All Underworlds exist simultaneously in the Overworld, however I do not believe the books ever explain how this actually works - I have never seen an Overworld map for Scion (it may exist, but it's not in the books).
- I do not believe the books directly explain how decisions are made for who goes where when they die. Most likely it is based on their faith - in that case it is up to the GM in a Scion game to determine where today's souls are going.
- Manipulating ghosts and travelling to an Underworld falls under the Death purview, however there are some Psychopomp boons that can affect travel to/from anywhere in the Overworld
- Somewhere in the books it is mentioned that the Titans are breaking into the Mortal World through cracks in the Underworld. This could be an interesting tie-in to your game.

**Incorporating Scion Underworlds into Geist**

- Determine how decisions are made for who goes where when they die. This could be  their faith, or it could be their ethnicity, whatever you decide.
- Once you determine where a soul resides, use Geist rules to do whatever you need and incorporate the given Underworld for effect. If you want to go more in-depth with haggling for souls from gods and guardians, you could do that as well.

**Incorporating Geist Rules into Scion**

Scion already has (limited) methods of calling the dead and entering an Underworld through boons and relics. Any other Geist abilities would most likely be added Death/Psychopomp/Magic/Health purview boons or relic effects.

Hope this helps.